# Aprendiendo I/O. Posibilidad de mostrar resultado de un comando y error a continuación

Tags: linux, redirección

Estudiando las redirecciones y los pipelines no encuentro respuesta para la siguiente situación:

Supongamos que introduzco un comando en el prompt, y éste (aquí tengo dudas) puede:

1. Mostrar el resultado del comando.
2. Mostrar un error.
3. ¿Pero podría mostrar un resultado y a la vez un error?

No sé, como que un comando devuelve un resultado y ocurre un error con algo y muestra ese error...

En tal caso, ¿como podría recrear esto (no se me ocurre manera alguna) y redirigir el resultado del comando a un archivo y el error a otro?

Para los dos primeros casos lo tengo claro.

Gracias por vuestras respuestas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En Unix se tiene la convención de que un programa devuelve 0 en caso de éxito un número positivo en caso de advertencia (>0) y un número negativo en caso de error (<0).

Por convención los mensajes de error se escriben en *stderr*, las advertencias pueden aparecer tanto en *stdout* como en *stderr*, aunque se acostumbra *stderr* (casi obligatorio en caso de que *stdout* sea la propia salida del programa)

Supongamos que tienes un programa llamado *repetir* el cuál repite un texto *n* veces en *stdout*.

El programa hace lo siguiente:

- devuelve 0 en caso de éxito
- muestra advertencias en caso de que *n* sea impar, supon pérdidas de rendimiento (>0)
- error en caso de que *n* sea negativo (<0)

*repetir*

```
#!/bin/env  bash
if [ "$#" -ne 2 ]; then
    echo "error: invalid number of arguments" >&2
    exit -1
fi

if (( $1 < 0)); then
    echo "error: invalid argument \"$1\" is not a positive number" >&2
    exit -1;
fi

ret=0
if (( $1 % 2 == 1)); then
    echo "warning: n is odd. Wait this will take some time" >&2
    sleep 5s
    ret=1
fi

for (( i = 0; i < $1; i++ )) do
    echo $2
done

exit $ret
```

Salidas particulares:

```
$ ./repetir 4 "Hola mundo"
Hola mundo
Hola mundo
Hola mundo
Hola mundo

$ ./repetir 5 "Hola mundo"
warning: n is odd. Wait this will take some time
Hola mundo
Hola mundo
Hola mundo
Hola mundo
Hola mundo
```

Ahora respondiendo:

> ...podría mostrar un resultado y a la vez un error?

Sí, como puedes ver el hacer `./repetir 5 "hola mundo"` muestra un error, en este caso concreto el error es que se imprime un número impar de líneas y suponemos que esto degrada exponencialmente el rendimiento de la aplicación (tarda más). No obstante este error es recuperable, es decir la aplicación puede seguir su curso y dar la salida correcta, así que la aplicación muestra un mensaje y a la vez la salida del programa.

> ¿como podría... redirigir el resultado del comando a un archivo y el error a otro?

Para obtener el resultado basta con que redirigas *stdout* a un archivo y *stderr* a otro

```
 $ command >salida.txt 2>error.txt
```

Ejemplo:

```
$ ./repetir 5 "Hola mundo" >salida.txt 2>error.txt

$ cat salida.txt
Hola mundo
Hola mundo
Hola mundo
Hola mundo
Hola mundo

$ cat error.txt
warning: n is odd. Wait this will take some time
```

Si quieres ignorar los errores basta con que redirigas *stderr* a */dev/null*

```
$ command 2>/dev/null
```

Ejemplo:

```
$ ./repetir 5 "Hola mundo" 2>/dev/null
Hola mundo
Hola mundo
Hola mundo
Hola mundo
Hola mundo
```

Nota:
Esto funciona únicamente si el programa sigue las convenciones que puse al principio.
En el caso de Windows muchos programas fallan y siguen devolviendo 0 (éxito), también se da el caso en que los errores están en *stdout* en lugar de *stderr* complicando la separación de la salida y los mensajes de error. En estos casos deberás utilizar alguna herramienta de texto como grep, awk, o sed.

Comment: Magnífica respuesta, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Algo que también puedes hacer, aunque a mi consideración es algo "extremo". Es redirigir todos los errores de la terminal a un archivo.

La terminal es un programa, y como todo programa tiene descriptores de archivo para comunicarse con otros.

Puedes ver los descriptores de archivo que tiene este proceso en su carpeta de información en `/proc/<pid>/fd`

Para saber el pid de tu terminal puedes hacer esto `$ echo $$` y te desplegará el pid de tu terminal en curso, digamos que resulta algo así.

```
$ echo $$
13
```

Entonces "13" es el pid de tu terminal. Ahora ejecutas esto:

```
$ ls -la /proc/13/fd  # recuerda que esto es sólo un ejemplo de pid.
total 0
dr-x------ 2 usuario usuario 0 Oct 10 23:38 .
dr-xr-xr-x 7 usuario usuario 0 Oct 10 23:38 ..
lrwx------ 1 usuario usuario 0 Oct 11 23:12 0 -> /dev/tty3  #nota estos descriptores de archivo
lrwx------ 1 usuario usuario 0 Oct 11 23:10 1 -> /dev/tty3  #este
lrwx------ 1 usuario usuario 0 Oct 11 23:10 10 -> /dev/tty3
lr-x------ 1 usuario usuario 0 Oct 11 23:10 12 -> /usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion.zwc
lrwx------ 1 usuario usuario 0 Oct 11 23:10 2 -> /dev/tty3 # y este. Trabajaremos con este.
```

Este programa lo corrimos para hacer un rollback más adelante. Mientras hay que quedarnos con el dato de que el *fd* 2 es un enlace simbólico a `/dev/tty3`

Ahora te presento `exec`. Es un built-in de bash que reemplaza la terminal con el comando que pongas, pero también sirve para redirigir los descriptores de archivo.

Recuerda que el stderr tiene como descriptor de archivo el número 2, entonces puedes aplicar esto.

```
$ exec 2> /ruta/archivo/errores.log # y luego puedes correr todas las atrocidades que quieras.
$ asdf 
$ cat archivo_inexistente
$ ls archivo_inexistente
```

Y no verás los errores en la consola, estarán todos en el archivo errores.log que, al usar cat para mostar su cotenido, arrojará algo de este estilo.

```
$ cat /ruta/de/errores.log
zsh: command not found: lasdf
zsh: command not found: asdfasd
zsh: command not found: edc
zsh: command not found: edfvrf
cat: asdfa: No such file or directory
cat: sd: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'ygvc': No such file or directory
```

Que han sido todos los errores que has tenido desde que redireccionaste el stderr de la terminal.

Para volver a la normalidad sólo vuelve a ejecutar el comando `exec` redirigiendo el stderr al archivo al que estaba ligado, recordemos que era `/dev/tty3`

```
$ exec 2> /dev/tty3
```

Y volverás a ver los errores en tu terminal a partir de ahora.

Algo que no vi que se mencionara es el símbolo `&`. Esto es útil en casos de tener registros verbosos o silenciosos.

Por ejemplo, para redireccionar tanto stdout como stderr a un archivo, se puede hacer esto.

```
$ comando >archivo 2>&1
$ comando &> archivo
```

Ambos formas son equivalentes. Y a veces puede ayudar para únicamente correr procesos sin saber lo que pasa en su interior y conocer únicamente el estado de salida. Por ejemplo.

```
comando_o_funcion_rara &> /dev/null
if [[ "$?" == 0 ]] 
then
    #Código de que el programa anterior salió bien.
else
    #Código de que el programa anterior salió mal.
fi
```

Un caso con el que recientemente me encontré fue al crear un sistema de reportes que consultaba a una base de datos a través de un proxy.

Como eran muchas consultas a realizar, tenía un módulo con muchas consultas editables al vuelo, pero, como suele suceder muchas veces, hice el programa muy largo y complejo sin probar cada cambio que hacía hasta el final. Los resultados de las consultas no salían como esperaba así que para depurar se me ocurrió mostrar las consultas a través del stderr, ya que el stdout de cada función en cada módulo sería requerido por otra función que la fuera a llamar, por lo que no podía mezclar en el código ambos descriptores de archivo o usar el stdout para depurar.

Todo corrió bien, obtuve las respuestas (erróneas) de las consultas a la db y sus consultas correspondientes sin que interfirieran, pero eran tantas consultas y tantos datos que necesitaba verlas al mismo tiempo y lentamente. Así que "pipee" la salida a `less` pero sólo me mostraba los datos y no las consultas... claro, por pipee el **stdout** del sistema a `less` y las consultas iban al stderr, por lo que redireccioné el stderr al stdout y luego lo pase por `less`.

```
$ programa 2>&1 | less
```

Es decir, al conectar por pipes los programas o comandos, no se conectan y ya, sino que son sus descriptores de archivo los que se comunican entre si, y si no le especificas uno, el programa de la izquierda redirigen su stdout al stdin del de la derecha, y así consecutivamente. Y el stderr jamás se propagaría a través de estos.

Otro uso que le puedes dar es el siguiente:

```
$ comando1 | comando2 2> /dev/null | comando3
#                       |             |___ Este comando corre bien
#                       |__________________Este no arroja nada por su stderr así que 
#                                          no habrá confusiones cuando termine la 
#                                          ejecución de toda la línea.
```